# How to check integrity of a catalog file of a windows driver?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have drivers with security catalog files included (catalogFile=someFile.cat).  I would like to check the validity of those drivers using the included security catalog file.

Which tools are included in Windows 7 to check a security catalog file?  What is the best practice?

How can i check the integrity of drivers?

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: [Tools for Signing Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The [Microsoft Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513/) includes the following tools
>   that you can use to create a code-signing certificate, to sign the
>   catalog file of a driver package, and to embed a signature in a driver
>   file:
>
> - CertMgr
> - Inf2Cat
> - MakeCat
> - MakeCert
> - Pvk2Pfx
> - SignTool

**SignTool** is used to verify that a catalog file is signed by a valid commercial release certificate (see below).

Source: [Verifying the Signature of a Catalog File Signed by a Commercial Release Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> To verify that a catalog file is signed by a valid commercial release
>   certificate, use the following SignTool command:
>
> SignTool verify /v /pa CatalogFileName.cat
>
> To verify that a file that is listed in a driver package's catalog
>   file is signed by a valid commercial release certificate, use the
>   following SignTool command:
>
> SignTool verify /v /pa /c CatalogFileName.cat DriverFileName
>
> Where:
>
> - The verify command configures SignTool to verify the signature of the driver package's catalog file CatalogFileName.cat or the driver
>     file DriverFileName.
> - The /v option configures SignTool to print execution and warning messages.
> - The /pa option configures SignTool to verify that the signature of the catalog file or driver file complies with the PnP driver
>     installation requirements.
> - CatalogFileName.cat is the name of the catalog file for a driver package.
> - The /c CatalogFileName.cat option specifies a catalog file that includes an entry for the file DriverFileName.
> - DriverFileName specifies the name of a file that has an entry in the catalog file CatalogFileName.cat.

Comment: How can I check that WDK is installed?  I have only `certmgr.msc`!

Comment: https://www.osr.com/blog/2014/05/28/wdk-version-running/ might give you some ideas

Comment: I SDK and then the tool was installed in the bin directory in the SDK installation directroy.

Comment: As far as I can tell, (and supported by http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/), this is necessary but not sufficient for the driver to actually work, and doesn't guarantee that the driver will actually be permitted to load